# How does this placeholder generator work?

Tags: c++, generics

I found this [placeholder generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663012/binding-a-generic-member-function/21664270#21664270) code which allows you to generate a sequence of a ints based off of the generic type template.

```
template<int...> struct int_sequence {};

template<int N, int... Is> struct make_int_sequence
    : make_int_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...> {};
template<int... Is> struct make_int_sequence<0, Is...>
    : int_sequence<Is...> {};

template<int> // begin with 0 here!
struct placeholder_template
{};

#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

namespace std
{
    template<int N>
    struct is_placeholder< placeholder_template<N> >
        : integral_constant<int, N+1> // the one is important
    {};
}
```

I know the applications of it, but how exactly does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your link to the original code, there's a lot missing.  I'm guessing that you are asking about the snippet you copied here though.

There are two parts to this snippet, both unrelated without the larger context.  The first is `int_sequence` and `make_int_sequence`.

First, the purpose: `make_int_sequence<3>` inherits from `int_sequence<0, 1, 2>`.  `int_sequence` is just a type container for a set of indices, and `make_int_sequence<N>` is a generator type that generates the `int_sequence` of indices from 0 to N-1.

If you follow the code, `make_int_sequence<3>` inherits from `make_int_sequence<2, 2>`, which inherits from `make_sequence<1, 1, 2>`, which inherits from `make_sequence<0, 0, 1, 2>`, which inherits from `int_sequence<0, 1, 2>`.

(In C++14, there exists `std::integer_sequence` and friends to do this.)

The second part is `placeholder_template`.  Since `std::placeholders::_1`, `_2`, etc., are of indeterminate type, the way we can make our own is to create a type, and then specialize `std::is_placeholder` for that type.  In this case that type is `placeholder_template`.  The comment about `// the one is important` refers to the fact that `placeholder_template<0>` acts like `_1`, both of which must inherit from `std::integral_constant<int, 1>`.

The actual code from the link then uses `make_integer_sequence` to build a 0-based set of indices, and then generates a placeholder for each.